# How to build a JUnit 4 test for void methods

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have tried to use Mockito's verify in my JUnit test like this

I want to the and verify this methods

in my class of SocketEngine. How to use Mockito for verify this test? I have search how to use Mockito for void methods but I still get an error like that. and how to fix this problem.

I got error like this: the method verify(T) not applicable for void arguments

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `verify` wrong. It isn't:

```
verify((socketEngine.read(server, readerString)));
```

It's:

```
verify(socketEngine).read(server, readerString);
```